# Automatic brightness / adaptive dimming basically making Ubuntu unusable - Asus UX303L

Tags: 18.04, brightness, asus

My laptop has some sort of adaptive brightness/dimming feature, and while it isn't an issue on Windows, Ubuntu uses the feature and almost gives me epilepsy. Every other second, the screen either dims or becomes slightly brighter. Sometimes I am writing and it just goes from super bright to almost pitch black. I was playing EU4 recently and the screen just went black, like if it turned off (the light in my room is dark, but not that dark).

My computer is running Ubuntu 18.04, is an asus zenbook ux303ln, with an intel hd and a gt 940m.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: My UX305F has the same issue. Fn-A also does nothing. Had to disable the feature in settings. Maybe one day the algorithm will be usable.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. You can just disable the automatic brightness setting. It is under "settings->power"

Hope that works!

Answer (score 1):

There is a [guide](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/disable-ambient-light-sensor-asus-49601.html) for turning off adaptive brightness. Here is a summary:

1. Lift up and open the LCD display panel with your thumb. Press the "Power" button beneath the display to turn the laptop on.
2. Locate the Function key, labeled <kbd>Fn</kbd> at the bottom of the keyboard.
3. Press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to turn off the Ambient Light Sensor.
4. Press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to manually adjust the screen brightness.

Comment: This is not working in ubuntu